# How to split result of a cell if there is no special character exists in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help to  replace some characters from the string while there is no any special

character exists.I have a table with some value like "3130 3210 N JOG ROAD" and "30 - 36 N Lorance blvd".

I want to remove first character set that is 3130 and 30.

so my final result should be "3210 N JOG ROAD" and "36 N Lorance blvd"

My table data is like..

---

3130 3210 N JOG ROAD

---

30 - 36 N Lorance blvd

---

78 Arx Street

---

90, RockWell

and expected result is

---

3210 N JOG ROAD

---

36 N Lorance blvd

---

78 Arx Street

---

90, RockWell

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is space between them to split. xyz=Split(String," ")

Comment: yes but it also remove the character if there is " " in other string.. please suggest if there is any way to find such type of pattern or something new idea.. thanks

Comment: If commactr > 1 Then
                    cellval_tmp = Split(Split(cellval, ",")     (commactr), " ")
                        cellval11 = ""
                        'MsgBox cellval_tmp(1)
                        For k = 1 To UBound(cellval_tmp)
                            cellval11 = cellval11 & " " &     Trim(cellval_tmp(k))
                        Next
                        cellval = Split(cellval, ",")(0) & cellval11
                        
                        Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(i, col).Value =     cellval
                    Else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Split() function:

```
Msgbox Split("3130 3210 N JOG ROAD"," ",2)(1)
```

Comment: Great help but if somewhere my value is "210 T Lake ROAD" than it also remove 210 from it.. Need an hardcore solution that if somewhere control found only this "3130 3210 N JOG ROAD" type of value than run this code..

Comment: This code will remove 210 as well. It splits the String at the first blank. All you need to do is iterate through the cells with data and apply the Split function to every cell.

Comment: but how to find such type of cell which contains such type of data so that if i again run the script it produce same result..

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim xyz As String
Dim spltVal As Variant
Public Sub Split_String()
    xyz = "3210 N JOG ROAD"
    spltVal = Split(xyz, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(spltVal)
        Debug.Print spltVal(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Try this, I hope this may help you

Comment: It's very simple to avoid or remove some values i.e. just write a condition to avoid to get that value into another array.